# Counting similiar SQL rows

Tags: mysql

I have two simple tables:

User:

```
Id|Name
1 |A
2 |B
3 |C
```

and Vehicle Assingment:

```
User_Id|Vehicle_Type
1      |Car
1      |Boat
2      |Car
2      |Car
3      |Boat
```

Notice that it is possible that 1 User has more then 1 vehicle assingment.

I'm trying to group them up so I will have the following View:

```
Name|Vehicle_Type|User_Id_Count_per_Vehicle_Type
A   |Car         |1
A   |Boat        |1
B   |Car         |2
C   |Boat        |1
```

So i tried the following Query:

```
SELECT User.Name,va.Vehicle_Type, COUNT(User.Id) FROM User
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Vehicle_Assingment) va
ON User.Id = va.user_Id
GROUP BY User.Id
```

But I get the following result:

```
Name|Vehicle_Type|User_Id_Count_per_Vehicle_Type
A   |Car         |2
B   |Car         |2
C   |Boat        |1
```

So it seems that I am grouping incorrectly.

Comment: `GROUP BY User.Id` should be `GROUP BY User.Id,va.Vehicle_Type`

Comment: `COUNT(User.Id)` should be `COUNT(*)`

Comment: IłyaBursov The first comment solved it for me, why do i also need to change it to COUNT(*)?

Comment: http://sqlversity.com/difference-between-count-and-count-column-name/